# FFMPEG + V4L2 OPTIONS

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, v4l2

I am looking for a way to integrate the parameters of v4l2-ctl on ffmpeg
the problem what ffmpeg overwrite v4l2-ctl and I need specific parameter has v4l2-ctl :(
my v4l2-ctl commands is :

v4l2-ctl -v width=640,height=480,pixelformat=4 -p 30 -c h264_profile=0,repeat_sequence_header=1

I want to use these parameters to then stream directly with FFMPEG
how can I do ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can tell FFmpeg to use video4linux2 (v4l2) as an input "device" ([which it treats like a demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#Device-Options)). Depending on your device, v4l2 can provide video in several different formats (for example, raw video  like yuv420p, or compressed video like h264, possibly via a hardware accelerator). It looks like you are trying to use h264, so you are probably looking for something along these lines:

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -input_format h264 -video_size 640x480 -framerate 30 -i /dev/video0 out.h264
```

FFmpeg will tell v4l2 to provide an h264-encoded stream with the given framerate and size as an input to ffmpeg, which will copy the stream into the file `out.h264`. You will need to specify your output format and options depending on your use case.

> Note: this assumes your input device is `/dev/video0`. You can use `v4l2-ctl --list-devices` to see which devices are available.

It is not clear from the [ffmpeg documentation for v4l2](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#video4linux2_002c-v4l2) how to provide additional flags (such as `h264_profile` and `repeat_sequence_header`) to v4l2. FFmpeg does provide a [multitude of options](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#Codec-Options) for encoding, but those may require you to specify a raw video  `-input_format` from v4l2 and use FFmpeg's x264 encoder instead, which could be much slower than a hardware encoder.

> Disclaimer: this question probably belongs on Super User or Video Production rather than Stack Overflow, since it only deals with the command-line tool.